# Nimrod Hunter installation issue - gives message "nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Tags: javascript, bash, heroku, nim-lang

I've been trying to setup Nimrod hunter on my windows 10. I've been following this guide: https://www.scrappycabin.com/products/nimrod-hunter-your-secret-email-finder/?access=PQV4H2XU&plan_id=4

I don't have a coding background. I've downloaded the source code and Node js  installer for windows.

I created the Heroku account and downloaded the Heroku Command Line Interface (CLI). Also installed the Git.

I saved Nirod on my desktop. The guide says "make sure you're in the NimrodHunter folder" so I Git bashed the Nimrodhunter folder.

Then I typed "git add ." as told in the guide. But when I type in the 2nd command i.e "git commit -m"Ready to launch" it says "On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Stuck here :( What should I do?

Comment: Looking at the instructions to install Nimrod I'd have to say it will be very hard to do without some experience with the tools they are using. You may get stuck on every single step of the instructions (I know I would, and I know a thing or two about those things). My suggestion is to find someone with some knowledge of Node.js to guide you.

Comment: hmm I wanted to do this on my own. I'll try the whole thing on Linux and see if it goes through.